# how to delete access_log's content periodically & how to code "if (array=nothing) then..." in bash script

Tags: arrays, apache, bash, logging

First, I want to delete access_log's content periodically every 5min (/var/log/httpd/access_log). Please tell me how to do that??

Second, in bash script, I define a array:

```
array=$(awk '{print $4}' /var/log/httpd/sample | uniq -c | cut -d[ -f1)
```

Now, I want to know how to use if command with this content:

```
"if there is NOT any element in array, it means array=nothing, then echo "nothing in array".
```

This is a sample script about array:

```
# Tinh n2
arr=(${array[*]})
for (( i=(${#arr[@]} - 2),j=(${#arr[@]} - 1); i >= (${#arr[@]} - 2) , j > (${#arr[@]} - 2); i--,j-- )); do
  b=$( expr ${arr[j]} - ${arr[i]} )
  n2=$(abs $b)
done 
echo "n2 = $n2"
```

Please tell me how to code that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate a file, add this command to your crontab configuration file :

```
 > /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

NOTE : The '>' is required

To check for an empty array, test the element count

```
if [ ${#array[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Array is empty"
else
    echo "We have nail"
fi
```